# How to turn on & off 50W LED when already using a driver according to limit switches?

Tags: switching, led-driver

I have a 50W UV LED that is going to be installed on a UV printer's head. The printer's head raster, as printers usually do. I would like to turn the LED on only when reaching the printing surface and turn it off when when passing it. This is in order to minimize the usage of the LED. This helps to keep it running cooler, for a longer time.

The way I thought to sense the head positioning is using optical "slot" sensors, mounted one on each end of the active printing area.

The LED is driven by a CC power supply which has a potentiometer that controls how much to dim the LED. I would like to set a working point using the potentiometer.

So my question is how to do that exactly in a safe way? I understand that I probably want to toggle between two settings of resistance. LED on represented by a certain setting of the potentiomer and LED off is represented by another setting. A naive approach could use a few relays, however I would rather avoid mechanical switching due to all the noise that it creates and the fear that even after mitigation it might hurt the LED or the power supply.

Suggestions are welcomed!

Comment: How this can be done depends on the design of the LED driver, for example, is the potmeter part of a **mains isolated** circuit or not? If it is not then that complicates things. Instead of relays you could use opto-isolators but how that would need to connect to the driver again depends on its design.

Comment: you could probably use an n-channel mosfet to short out half the pot in a way that makes it's current minimal or zero.

Comment: Use a programmable digipot if multiple resistance values will solve your problem.  Maybe.  Not enough is known about your circuit or what resources you have available.